# Ways to ruin a hobby

Tags: etymology, popular-refrains

### Variations

- *The best way to ruin a hobby is to make it a career.*
- *The fastest way to ruin a hobby is to try to make money with it.*
- *The quickest way to ruin a hobby is to make it a job.*

What's the history behind this saying? Is it attributable to a particular person?

(I imagine the complementary maxim would be *Do what you love.*)

Comment: It seems to me that this kind of questions are off-topic but someone more knowledgeable can probably tell. These expressions are not ambiguous, are very easy to understand with current english, do not use archaic words or constructs.

Comment: I would also claim that this is off-topic, even though it is a very interesting question. Relationships between work and play are radically different among societies that are hunter-gatherers, agrarian, capitalist, etc. So while this can be viewed as an etymology (evolution of words) question, it has more to do with history, anthropology, and such (evolution of ideas).

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to the provenance of the particular variations you cite, but the sentiment goes back at least as far as *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer* by Mark Twain:

> Tom said to himself that it was not such a hollow world, after all. He had discovered a great law of human action, without knowing it -- namely, that in order to make a man or a boy covet a thing, it is only necessary to make the thing difficult to attain. If he had been a great and wise philosopher, like the writer of this book, he would now have comprehended that Work consists of whatever a body is *obliged* to do, and that Play consists of whatever a body is not obliged to do. And this would help him to understand why constructing artificial flowers or performing on a tread-mill is work, while rolling ten-pins or climbing Mont Blanc is only amusement. There are wealthy gentlemen in England who drive four-horse passenger-coaches twenty or thirty miles on a daily line, in the summer, because the privilege costs them considerable money; but if they were offered wages for the service, that would turn it into work and then they would resign.

Answer (score 1):

The oldest reference to any "* ruin a hobby" I found is from the [September 1985](http://books.google.com/books?id=VR8DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22+ruin+a+hobby%22&hl=en&ei=rzuhTuiKGMiH4gT9uojTBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20ruin%20a%20hobby%22&f=false)  *Cincinnati Magazine*:

> Nothing will ruin a hobby more effectively than the feeling that your spouse resents it.

And "* ruin my hobby" in a [1985](http://books.google.com/books?id=-cAaAQAAMAAJ&q=%22+ruin+my+hobby%22&dq=%22+ruin+my+hobby%22&hl=en&ei=kjyhTseYK8b04QTF8bXqBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ) article in *Runner's World*:

> Roy Benson gave up his full- time job with the Atlanta Track Club, he says in Racing South magazine, because "I don't want my job to ruin my hobby. Running is my hobby, my first love. I just don't want to burn out on it. ...

And finally, very neatly, "* ruin your hobby" is also from 1985, in *Creative Crafts and Miniatures*:

> In the long run, too many shows can ruin your hobby.

The first and last of these don't have the same meaning, but the second is spot on.